# A question about grammar. MS Outlook grammar correction for "equipment register"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, register

Outlook is questioning "equipment register" and asking me to double check if I am using singular or plural (error underline on the word register). This has me really confused and I can't find any information about what could be wrong with this phrase.

For context, the phrase is part of a list of other items and I am using it to mean a register of equipment, like you would have a register of users, or a register of stock...etc. I get no grammar errors if I replace "equipment" with other words (although obviously I haven't exhausted all possible words!)

If I write "An equipment register" the error remains. If I write "One equipment register" it goes away.

Thanks!

Comment: Eh - I once had a grammar checker ask me if I wanted to change a possessive "its" to "it's". I'd just ignore it and move on.

Comment: Perhaps Outlook thinks it's a *verb* usage, as in [*Our equipment **registers** ground disturbances all along the western border.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Our+equipment+registers+ground%22)

Comment: **equipment register** is a rare collocation. Change it to **equipment list** and I bet there will be no complaint from Outlook.   Especially since a register can be a piece of equipment.

Comment: With the full sentence we'd likely be able to tell. FYI, "closed" means *closed for answers*, not *gone*. I don't see the exact reason, but not including enough details, not doing research, and other reasons are easily overcome.

Comment: Full sentence included in original question. I understand what closed for answers means. I have already said that I can't find the answer anywhere else, it's implied by the asking of the question here. Full details are included, it's a simple question, not complicated. Demonstrably on-topic question, so can only assume a moderator hasn't read the help centre guidance and is just guessing because they don't understand the question. In which case that should be the reason for closing, not being off topic. It's hard to edit a clearly on topic question to make it even more on topic.

Comment: Without access to the code for Outlook's grammar checker, there's no way of knowing _why_ it chose to flag those words.

Comment: That implies that only Outlook knows any rules of grammar and we humans can't know why anything gets flagged. I find the opposite to be true and it's usually easy to work out why something is flagged. But this one is not obvious and that is interesting to me. Might not be to others, but hopefully someone finds it interesting enough to think of a reason.

Comment: This site is for questions about English, not for second-guessing the reasons that grammar checkers are completely wrong.

Comment: True, and that is not what the question is about at all.